# Python Django:Form validation with pure HTML

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I would like to use pure HTML in django  ie  i don't want to use django auto generated form tags suppose i have an html markup like this

```
<form action="sample/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

So how can i add the form validation to the above form??

Now i am using form class to generate forms and the validation code look like this

```
if request.method=='POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('form ok')
        else:
            return render(request, 'templates/form.html', {'form': form,'t':'form submit'})
    else:
        form=NameForm()
        return render(request, 'templates/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'add the validation rules'. See the docs on [working with forms in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates), in particular the section on error messages.

Comment: It means form validation

Comment: you need to write your own validation I suppose - since you don't want to use Django's form framework you are on your own ;)

Comment: Nop i need the django form validation but don't need the auto generated form elements

Comment: So why do you think there would be any affect on validation?

Comment: When I use pure html how can i get   `form` variable ie`form=NameForm()`

Comment: I can't understand that question. Why should it change at all?

Comment: You could add `{{ form.errors }}` above the form in your template. That will render the errors from the form.

Comment: @daniel let me edit my question.